# "Would you be kind enough to answer me?" Or: "Could you kindly answer me?"

Tags: difference, politeness, will-would

Do these two sentences have the same meaning? Which of these phrases sounds more natural?

> Would you be kind enough to answer me?

Or:

> Could you kindly answer me?

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are correct and have the same meaning. However, they are extremely formal. Less formal options are to substitute "please" for the use of "kindly":

> Please answer me.

> Could/Would/Can you please answer me?